# Using Angular Material table mat-text-column in a wrapper table

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-components, angular-material-table

I'm using Angular Material tables and I've built a wrapped table like https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material-examples/table-wrapped. Is there a way I can `mat-text-column` in my wrapped table? When I do the following:

```
<wrapper-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [columns]="displayedColumns" matSort #sort="matSort">
    <mat-text-column name="firstName"></mat-text-column>
</wrapper-table>
```

I get `Error: Could not find column with id "firstName".`